# Links and parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, parameters, hyperlink

I am trying to get a series of links working. Some should be toggleable and some not.

Basically on a page reload my params hash already has two keys in it which it should not have and I cannot see where they are being added.

My links:

```
<ul class="all filter__group">
  <li><%= link_to "View all", coasters_path(page: 1), remote: true %></li>
</ul>

<ul class="types filter__group">
  <%= content_tag(:li, class: ("active" if params[:type] == "steel")) do %>
    <%= link_to "Steel", coasters_path(type_parameters("steel", page: 1)), remote: true %>
  <% end %>
  <%= content_tag(:li, class: ("active" if params[:type] == "wood")) do %>
    <%= link_to "Wood", coasters_path(type_parameters("wood", page: 1)), remote: true %>
  <% end %>
  <%= content_tag(:li, class: ("active" if params[:type] == "powered")) do %>
    <%= link_to "Powered", coasters_path(type_parameters("powered", page: 1)), remote: true %>
  <% end %>
</ul>

<ul class="letters filter__group">
  <%= content_tag(:li, class: ("active" if params[:letters] == "#")) do %>
    <%= link_to "#", coasters_path(letter_parameters("#", page: 1)), remote: true %>
  <% end %>
  <%= content_tag(:li, class: ("active" if params[:letters] == "a-e")) do %>
    <%= link_to "A-E", coasters_path(letter_parameters("a-e", page: 1)), remote: true %>
  <% end %>
  <%= content_tag(:li, class: ("active" if params[:letters] == "f-j")) do %>
    <%= link_to "F-J", coasters_path(letter_parameters("f-j", page: 1)), remote: true %>
  <% end %>
  <%= content_tag(:li, class: ("active" if params[:letters] == "k-o")) do %>
    <%= link_to "K-O", coasters_path(letter_parameters("k-o", page: 1)), remote: true %>
  <% end %>
  <%= content_tag(:li, class: ("active" if params[:letters] == "p-t")) do %>
    <%= link_to "P-T", coasters_path(letter_parameters("p-t", page: 1)), remote: true %>
  <% end %>
  <%= content_tag(:li, class: ("active" if params[:letters] == "u-z")) do %>
    <%= link_to "U-Z", coasters_path(letter_parameters("u-z", page: 1)), remote: true %>
  <% end %>
</ul>
<%= debug params %>
```

Helper methods:

```
  # Add the type parameter to URL if not already there and remove if they are
  def type_parameters(type, options = {})
    parameters = {}
    if params[:type] == type
      # Get exisiting params
      parameters = params
      # Remove type
      parameters.delete(:type)
      # Merge any parameters passed in via options
      parameters.merge!(options)
    else
      # Get exisiting params
      parameters = params
      #Add type to new parameters variable
      parameters.merge!(type: type)
      # Merge any parameters passed in via options
      parameters.merge!(options)
    end
    parameters
  end

  # Add the letters parameter to URL if not already there and remove if they are
  def letter_parameters(letters, options = {})
    parameters = {}
    if params[:letters] == letters
      # Get exisiting params
      parameters = params
      # Remove letters
      parameters.delete(:letters)
      # Merge any parameters passed in via options
      parameters.merge!(options)
    else
      # Get exisiting params
      parameters = params
      #Add letters to new parameters variable
      parameters.merge!(letters: letters)
      # Merge any parameters passed in via options
      parameters.merge!(options)
    end
    parameters
  end
```

On a page reload this is the current params hash:

```
--- !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
action: index
controller: coasters
type: powered
page: 1
letters: u-z
```

Any ideas on where I am going wrong?

Comment: Could you show us the controller action?

Comment: The controller action: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8383369

Comment: Are you sure you are not reloading an URL containing `letters=u-z`?

Comment: Positive. I have just tried accessing it from a new tab. Retyping the URL from scratch and even typing it from scratch in a different browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overriding the params hash from within the helpers: when you are using `merge!` you are overriding the original `params` hash.

This should work:

```
# Add the letters parameter to URL if not already there and remove if they are
  def letter_parameters(letters, options = {})
    parameters = params.dup

    if params[:letters] == letters
      # Remove letters
      parameters.delete(:letters)
    else
      # Add letters to new parameters variable
      parameters.merge!(letters: letters)
    end

    # Merge any parameters passed in via options
    parameters.merge(options)
  end
```

Note the use of `dup` to create a new copy of the params hash

Comment: But where. As far as I can see, I am creating a new parameters variable which ends up as a hash containing the items to be used as parameters for that link when it is clicked on?  Is this not right?

Comment: I've added an explanation and some code which should make it clearer :)